# How to get data from Django One to Many Fields Model using views into templates

Tags: python, django, templates, view, model

I want to display 1 Parent Field with associated Child and further there Childs

I have a Model

```
class GrandParent(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....

class Parent(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(GrandParent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....

class Child(models.Models):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
```

I am able to render objects from Grand Parent But I m unable to link further Parent Class objects and Child class objects in templates

This approach I used in views.py

```
def list(request):
    object_list = GrandParent.published.all()
    ...
    return render('app/list.html')

def detail(request, post,):

    post = get_object_or_404(GrandParent, slug=post,
                        status='published')
                               
    return render(request, 'app/detail.html',
                            {'post' : post,
                            ...
                            
                            })
```

Now how to link further Classes in Same Detail View But Associated with there Parent Classes using Foreign Key. I'm following Django docs but they only giving max 2 examples using python shell with just One subclass I m confused How to implement there in this structure. Or anyone have already developed any project specifically with this type of models so please share any link of repo or something, would be wonderful.

#list.html
{% extends "_base.html" %}

```
{% block title %} mysite{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


    <h2>Content </h2>

    
    <ul>
        {% for post in object_list %}
        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
            <li>{{ post.name}}</li></a>
                
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

#detail.html

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}



{% block title %} freeStreams {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="card-body">
    <h1 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h1>

</div>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you add more detail? Where you want show parent class and child? In template view `detail.html`? Can you show code of it?

Comment: Sure ... I edited  Question Part. please look into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access from one to many in view template by for loop all child of it. In your case, with `GrandParent` by `post.parent_set.all()`. For `Child` by  `parent.child_set.all()`. You can try first in terminal for check you have correct database and relation.

Add it inside block `content`

detail.html

```
        {% for parent in post.parent_set.all() %}
                <h1 class="card-title">{{ parent.name }}</h1>
                {% for child in parent.child_set.all() %}
                   <h2 class="card-title">{{ child.name }}</h2>
                    
                {% endfor %}    
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: you can't use all() inside templates